# Is there a better way to get an int result out of list comprehension than try except (when None or empty is involved)?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Editing for clarity:

I am using list comprehension to get out single fields from lists of data. I only want the integer value from the list comprehenions, but list comprehension gives me lists of lists. So for example, I'd pass in an ordered list of items, and get back an int quantity of used items, except it won't give me a list of ints. it will give me a list like this: [[1], [2], [5], [60], [0], [], [], [4]] (I will have None values in here as well at times since I'm pulling from a database with missing values, which may be a problem in itself. But that is not the focus of this question. I'd like to know if there are ways of getting the values without running into index errors.

```
resource['new_item'] = [item['used_qty'] for item in items if item['item_id'] == resource['item_id']]
    try:
        resource['new_item'] = resource['new_item'][0]
    except IndexError:
        resource['new_item'] = 0
```

Getting out single ints from list comprehension seems to be more difficult than it should be when there is the potential for None or empty arrays being involved.

One way I use when I have a list of single int lists, like this is:

```
a = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]
a = sum(a, [])
print(a)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

or

```
a[0]
```

Or I use:

```
a = [letter for letter in letters if letter == something].pop()
```

or

```
a = [letter for letter in letters if letter == something][0]
```

But all of these break if there is possibly a None or an empty array returned, which I am dealing with a lot in what I am working on now. Please share some good ways to get at the juicy int inside the list that are better than try, except.

Comment: the question as it worded is indeed confusing . what is new_item? what is used, and what is item_id? what is difference between `new_item` and `new_items`? these are the questions going thru my head and it's hard to match it against the question being asked, since part of the context is somewhat missing here.

Comment: The expected output is 1 but I get [1] or None but I get []. The input is just various numerical data where None is an acceptable option.

Comment: are `resource['new_item']` and `resource['new_items']` different?

Comment: @sahasrara62 typo, fixing now.

Comment: *"The input is just various numerical data where None is an acceptable option."* -  I am still kinda lost. So is it like `[a, 'b', None]` or like `[None, [...], [3]]`?

Comment: it's an integer value greater than 0 that does not exist in some cases.

Comment: It looks like the data structure that is created by your list comprehension is not suited to extracting the information you want from the data. Take a step back, unwind your list comprehensions into loops, and look at how you might augment those loops to perform the analysis you want while you are going through the data.

Comment: @BoarGules Are you suggesting that I can insert more logic or conditionals into the list comprehension itself?

Comment: No. I'm suggesting you *abandon the list comprehension entirely* and turn it into equivalent explicit loops, and put the logic in the loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure if I entirely understand the question, but you could try with `or` switch in python, which will evaluate second part after `or` if the first part is falsy, such as an empty list or `None` value as mentioned.

For example:

```py
resource['new_item'] = [item['used_qty'] or [0] for item in items if item['item_id'] == resource['item_id']]

# defaults to `0` if contains falsy value
resource['new_item'] = resource['new_item'][0]
```

Comment: I think 'or' is the best solution to minimize the need for the use of try, except. It helps me try to grab it and then assign a default if that doesn't work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
resource['new_item'] = 0
# just update first matching result
for item in items:
    if item['item_id']==resourc['item_id']:
        resource['new_item'] = item['used_qty']
        break
```